# Why a system logout occurs after the cache is cleared even though the login records are stored in the session?

Tags: php, session, cookies

When we login to the system, we are storing some records to the session and on logout the session is cleared out.

Now, when a user is logged into the system, how comes that the page is automatically logged out if user clears the cache from the browser?

We stored the login data to the session and at the time of clearing cache, we are clearing only the cookies and not the session, so basically are cookies affecting the logged in user data?.

Comment: yes, cookie is also created and stored in browser whenever a new session is created.

Comment: If a session is destroyed on your server,  there should be no need to destroy the cookie because then the ID in the cookie should be invalid.

Comment: Fixed some grammar and formatting and removed unnecessary thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your session id is stored into your cookies.

If you won't delete it and only clear other cookies,then your system won't logout automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The cookie stored in the browser contains the session id and this is what is used to identify the session.  If you delete the cookie, how will your server know which session to retrieve?  You can't delete the cookie if you want to retain the session